# How to know parent of leaf item in NestedList?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Is there a method which allows to know parent item of leaf tapped item?
that is like I have a Store with structure like this:

```
root: {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Parent1',
                items: [
                    { text: 'Child1', leaf: true },
                    { text: 'Child2', leaf: true },
                    ............
```

When I tap on leaf item I need to know which parent has this leaf item. I can't find anything about special method for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the itemtap & leafitemtap, the record gets passed to the listener.

From here, you can grab the parent record by using:

```
record.parentNode
```